# Replace substring in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a string "st xxx street st st" and i want to change to "street xxx street street street". I can replace middle st, but how can i replace others.
Here is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

SPACE=" "
input="st xxx street st st"
search_string="st"
replace_string="street"
output=${input//$SPACE$search_string$SPACE/$SPACE$replace_string$SPACE}
```

Comment: Why don't you use sed/awk etc.? With bash sth like `while [[ $input =~ (^|.* )st( .*|$) ]]; do input="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}street${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; done; echo "$input"` would work but it's too much work

Comment: it will work but its expensive as i have too many records.

Comment: @UmarAmin, Then as already suggested by oguz ismail try using sed or awk solutions, I think sed one is already posted.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks fam, but a solution with sed/awk is what OP exactly needs and I don't want to distract from that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `sed` if that is possible:

```
echo "$input" | sed 's/\bst\b/street/g'
```

`\b` in GNU `sed` refers to word boundaries.

Also refer: [How can I find and replace only if a match forms a whole word?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184815/how-can-i-find-and-replace-only-if-a-match-forms-a-whole-word)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that there are never any occurrences of `street` at line beginning or end.

I suggest you try this:

1. Make all `street` occurrences to `st`:

   ```
   output=${input//$SPACE$replace_string$SPACE/$SPACE$search_string$SPACE}
   ```
2. Now you can safely change `st` to `street` without the spaces:

   ```
   output2=${output//$search_string/$replace_string}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add this two

```
output=${output//$search_string$SPACE/$replace_string$SPACE}
output=${output//$SPACE$search_string/$SPACE$replace_string}
```

Update on comment, then with help of `|`

```
output="|${input//$SPACE$search_string$SPACE/$SPACE$replace_string$SPACE}|"
output=${output//"|$search_string$SPACE"/$replace_string$SPACE}
output=${output//"$SPACE$search_string|"/$SPACE$replace_string}
output=${output//|}
```

Or like Markante Makrele suggested

```
output=${input//$replace_string/$search_string}
output=${output//$search_string/$replace_string}
```

But better use sed.

Comment: second one will not work because " street" will be replaced with "streetreet"

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a 'simple-stupid' procedure, in which I first change all spaces to newlines, then search for (temporary) lines containing just 'st', which I change to street, and I revert the newlines back in the end.

```
input='anst xxx street st st'
echo "$input" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sed 's/^st$/street/g' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/ $/\n/'
```

output:

```
anst xxx street street street
```

*Words only containing st shall not be substitued.*